# Why is wrapping elements so much quicker with jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Check out the test: http://jsperf.com/wrap-with-jq

```
var s = $('<span />').text('my span');



s.wrap('<div id="myWrap" class="myClass"></div>').parent();
```

8,073 ops/sec

87% slower

```
s.wrap($('<div />', {
  'id': 'myWrap',
  'class': 'myClass'
}).parent());
```

72,955 ops/sec

Is there a reason this is so much faster creating a new element with jQuery?  I would have assumed it was slower due to having to wrap an element with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the link to jsPerf, I didn't know it :-)

Comment: curious what the `parent()` is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not that much different. There is a typo in your test...

```
s.wrap($('<div />', {
  'id': 'myWrap',
  'class': 'myClass'
// move `parent` call outside...
})).parent();
```

The way it was, you were creating an element, then finding it's parent, which ends up as an empty array (`[]`) which you then pass to `s.wrap`, so it is faster to wrap s with an empty array than to wrap it with a dom element, and then find the parent.

http://jsperf.com/wrap-with-jq/3

5,118 vs 4,149 ops / sec in favor of with jq

Answer (score 6):

It takes a long time to parse that string. By giving it an object full of properties, you're doing the bulk of the work for it, resulting in much faster times.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm dumb.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's all just guess here without examining the internals of both jQuery and the JS engine, but my guess is that the second option only has to create a single div and then assign it a few properties where the first option has to create a documentFragment, assign it some HTML which must be parsed.  So, it ends up being faster to just create an element and assign properties rather than create a fragment and give it some HTML.

Note, this is not always the case.  There are definitely times where giving the engine a string of HTML is faster than manually creating lots of elements so when performance optimization is needed, you do have to test and optimize based on the test results.

Further, different browser engines will likely give different results in different situations.

Comment: +1. jQuery reusing a single documentFragment is the key, not the string parsing.